# Generate a password protected CSV file using java (Android)

Tags: java, android, csv

I have created a CSV file using opencsv. Now all that i need is to make it password protected. I found solution like protecting a zip file , excel etc but not a csv file . Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?

Comment: Why dont u encrypt the file nd decrypt using d key

Comment: There's no special encryption for CSV files. You can choose any tool that encrypts files.

Comment: @NidhinPrathap i need a password protection when the user opens the csv file manually . Does encryption satisfies this case??